# How to loop while search in bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script searching for a specific string "request completed" in the log file of my application server. The script should continuously search for the string and if the string doesn't appear at least for 1 minute during the search then it should stop the application.

```bash
timeout 600 tail -f /path/to/log/file | grep -q "request completed"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "'request completed' found. Starting search again"
    while true; do
        timeout 600 tail -f /path/to/log/file | grep -q "request completed"
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            break
        fi
    done
else
   stop the application command
fi
```

If the string is found even after 5th line of the script, does it go back to search again or exit ?

My application should be stopped only if the string is not found at least for a minute. And the script should continue to search until the string is not getting generated in the log file. Can I achieve with the above script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your script will exit the loop as soon as the string is not found,so better to rewrite it like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

logfile="/path/to/log/file"
timeout=60
threshold=0

while true; do
    if tail -n 1 "$logfile" | grep -q "request completed"; then
        threshold=0
    else
        ((threshold++))
        if [ "$threshold" -ge "$timeout" ]; then
            echo "string not found for at least $timeout seconds. stopping the application."
            #add command to stop your application here
            break
        fi
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

**update 1**
according to your request I piped `tail -f "$logfile"` to a `while` loop that reads each line as it is appended to the log file and now  script checks if the line contains the desired string "request completed".

```
#!/bin/bash

logfile="/path/to/log/file"
timeout=60
threshold=0

tail -f "$logfile" | while read -r line; do
    if echo "$line" | grep -q "request completed"; then
        threshold=0
    else
        ((threshold++))
        if [ "$threshold" -ge "$timeout" ]; then
            echo "string not found for at least $timeout seconds. stopping the application."
            #add command to stop your application here
            break
        fi
    fi
done
```

**update 2**
according to your new request,one way is to move the while loop into a function and use the `timeout` command to impose a time limit on the execution of the function,in my script the `check_threshold` function is defined, and the `timeout` command is used to limit the execution of the function to 300 seconds (adjust as needed) and the log file is passed to the function using input redirection (`<`) to ensure the correct file is read!

```
#!/bin/bash

logfile="/path/to/log/file"
timeout=60
threshold=0

check_threshold() {
    while read -r line; do
        if echo "$line" | grep -q "request completed"; then
            threshold=0
        else
            ((threshold++))
            if [ "$threshold" -ge "$timeout" ]; then
                echo "String not found for at least $timeout seconds. Stopping the application."
                #command to stop application
                break
            fi
        fi
    done < "$logfile"
}

timeout 300 check_threshold
```

Comment: Thank you Freeman... instead of "tail -n 1 $logfile", can I use "tail -f "$logfile" ??

Comment: @user22350706 check my answer again.

Comment: Hi Freeman, thank you very much for your update. In this bash script if the log file doesn't write anything for 60 lines, that means script will hang at else loop because threshold ++ doesn't increment the value? Can I use timeout 300 tail -f "$logfile" | while read -r line; do........"

Comment: Hi Freeman, could you please help me with this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76879178/how-to-wait-and-read-from-curl-output

Comment: @user22350706 The question was closed, and I couldn't enter the answer below the question. If you want to ask another question, create it, but first let me know the time you want to ask the question so that if our hours are the same, I can provide you with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> should continuously search for the string

Then continuously read.

Do not use `$?` if you do not have to.

```
exec 10<log/file
timeout 0.1 cat <&10  # rewind to end of file
while true; do
  data=$(timeout 600 cat <&10)
  if (($? != 124)); then
     echo "cat failed!"
  fi
  if ! grep -q "request completed" <<<"$data"; then
    break
  fi
 done
```